# How to mock a default interface method with Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have an interface `Foo` with a `default` method:

```
public interface Foo {
    // ... other methods
    default Bar bar() {
        // ... complex operations calling various methods
        return bar;
    }
}
```

And I want to stub the default method. If I do this:

```
var foo = mock(Foo.class);
var bar = mock(Bar.class);
when(foo.bar()).thenReturn(bar);
     ^^^^^^^^^
```

The highlighted method call actually calls the default method implementation, which I'd like to avoid. Is it possible?

Comment: try `Mockito.doReturn(bar).when(foo).bar()`

Comment: Can't reproduce. Actual `default` method not invoked when I test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doReturn` pattern will work in this case

```
doReturn(bar).when(foo).bar();
```